# Is it possible to write an If/Else Statement for datatables.net child rows to remove null make the row say yes, no or leave blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I'm still new to datables.net and JSON data. Do you know whether there is a way I can write an If/Else statement inside the datatables.net table row?

In the **screenshot below**: This is how it displays.

[image]

1. Can I write an If/Else statement for the data field "Service Available?" to display as true = Yes, false = No? **Make it say Yes for true or No for false.**
2. Can I write an If/Else statement for the table row to display **empty or blank** if the database value is" **null**"?

```js
function format(d) {
  return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">' +
    '<tr>' +
      '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: #484848 ;">Register</td>' +
      '<td><a href="' + d.LinkForMoreInformation + '">' + "For More Information" + '</a></td>' +
    '<tr>' +
      '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: #484848 ;">Service Available?</td>' +
      '<td>' + d.IsAICPCMOffered + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
      '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: #484848 ;">Contact Name</td>' +
      '<td>' + d.ContactName + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
}
```

Comment: What if `d.LinkForMoreInformation` is `'" onclick="alert(&quot;Virus goes here&quot;)" data-foo="`? That would result in `<a href="" onclick="alert(&quot;Virus goes here&quot;)" data-foo="">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `if` statement to hide the row completely if `ContactName` is empty and a ternary to change the displayed value of `IsAICPCMOffered`. Something like this:

```
function format(d) {
  if (!d.ContactName || d.ContactName == 'null')
    return '';

  return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">' +
    '<tr>' +
      '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: #484848 ;">Register</td>' +
      '<td><a href="' + d.LinkForMoreInformation + '">' + "For More Information" + '</a></td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
      '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: #484848 ;">Service Available?</td>' +
      '<td>' + (d.IsAICPCMOffered ? 'Yes' : 'No') + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
      '<td style="font-weight: bold; color: #484848 ;">Contact Name</td>' +
      '<td>' + d.ContactName + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rory the Yes or No values you entered in the table cell worked great but the code broke with the two returns for some reason. ? The table only displayed the contact data and erased the others for some reason.

return '';  above the return <table

Comment: Try `return '<table></table>';`

Comment: Thank you for the if/else statement for the d.IsAICPCMOffered! :) That works beautifully! I'm going to use that same format for the other null areas since the if statement at the very top didn't work.